# oleaut32.dll missing some deps

Tags: windows, dll

I try to run app on Windows 10 PC. The app depends on oleaut32.dll - but it seems oleaut32.dll itself misses some deps:

[image: deps]

Some of them for ex. `api-ms-win-core-wow64-l1-1-0.dll` are present in system folder. But for example. `api-ms-win-core-wow64-l1-1-1.dll` is missing at all.

I tried to fix with `sfc /scannow` but without luck. What can be the solution? Download missing DLLs and place in system32 folder?

Comment: Hi, does the app give an error related to that dll ?

Comment: Actually app just crashes silently. I have a source code - when in debug mode it throws an exception that it can't load dll (and that dll inside relies on oleaut32). On other 2 PC (Windows 10 an 8) code runs as expected.

Comment: What is the build version of your Windows installation that you're running into problems? This DLL was [introduced in the 1803 version (April 2018)](https://docs.microsoft.com/pt-br/uwp/win32-and-com/win32-apis#apis-from-api-ms-win-core-wow64-l1-1-1dll), so if you're running any version earlier than that, that might be a problem.

Answer (score 0):

There are at least 18 distinct official versions of oleout32.dll.

The newest version of the 32-bit Oleaut32.dll is 10.0.10240.16384
and 6.1.7601.17567 version for 64 Bit.

There are differences from version to version and your program may need something specific form a different version.

so get the proper version, drop it into the program main path and make sure that path is read with priority.

You can get any of the versions from [here](http://www.dlldownloader.com/oleaut32-dll/).